# Problems with optix and cuda when using CLion

Tags: clion, optix

I have simply downloaded the OptiX SDK (7.1), and have obviously installed CUDA (11). When opening a sample project in CLion, everything runs as it should, however, all the optix libraries are unknown to the IDE. Do you know anything about this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! CLion uses CMake as a project model and a build system, so it's probably a CMake issue. In order to ask a precise question, you need to quote your `CMakeLists.txt`, specify your operating system, and paths you installed the libraries to. You may also need to read "how to ask questions" SO guide.